# Triple monitor with two different cards

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

My primary card is a GT 440, and my other card is a 9500 GT. I have two 9500 GT's, so I could run SLI if I had a bridge and theoretically get close to the same performance as one GT 440. The issue is I don't have a bridge at the moment, so I'm wondering if there is a solution that will allow me to use the GT 440 and 9500 GT simultaneously. I don't mean for SLI purposes, but potentially for a triple monitor or using the 9500 GT for physx.

The steps I took to attempt to achieve is this as follows:

1. Reboot into safe mode
2. Remove all drivers via Program Features
3. Install using 320.49 driver

In safe mode, I can see both the 9500 GT and GT 440 without any yellow exclamation points. When I boot regularly, 9500 GT has an exclamation point. It doesn't show up in the physx configuration, and not when I click detect in screen resolution (I've tried both monitor ports.) At one point when I removed the 9500 GT device software via Device Manager, windows installed a WDDM. Also, the existence of the 9500 GT also seemed to allow me to install geforce experience and physx software, whereas those options never appeared when the card wasn't installed. Is it possible that my GT 440 simply doesn't support it? The oddity is that in GPU-Z, before I had the 9500 GT, physx was unchecked. But after installing the driver with that option checked, it is checked in GPU-Z.

To clarify, I have HDMI and DVI on my GT 440, and a third monitor I want to plug into the 9500 GT, or enable physx for the 9500 GT.

Comment: What you want simply is not possible because of the hardware differences between the two cards.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've had trouble in the past simultaneously using two video adapters from the same manufacturer, because the cards' drivers would attempt to load in the same memory space and cause a bluescreen. It seems like this shouldn't be a problem with Nvidia cards, which all use the same driver package, but perhaps this is what Ramhound is referring to.

Comment: I just tried it with both 9500 GTs. The same issue arised, the card in the third slot was not getting recognized.